# Creating windows-7 library using c#

Tags: c#, windows-7

Windows-7 introduced a concept of virtual folder, called 'Libraries'.

I am working on implementing a Library with my custom action. The constraint is that, I have to stick to .NET version 2 for this :(

While looking around, I didn't find any native (c/C++) API for doing this. I am planning to use Interop (p-Invoke) to make a library once I get native APIs.

Could any one point to a link or documentation which might help. If somehow I can do this directly from c# (with .NET v2), that would be great.

Thank you,
John

Comment: I think you're out of luck with .net v2, as win7 comes with 3.5 (in case it helps, found .net v3.5 version: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack)

Comment: This might also help: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DDW7LibrariesLite.aspx

Comment: George Duckett, .net 2 apps will work under win 7 perfectly.

Comment: @ElDog: You may be able to run the apps, but i'm doubting the existence of a 2.0 API for windows 7 because it comes with 3.5. Sorry if i wasn't clear.

Comment: @ElDog: David put it better than i could in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of "virtual folder" exists already before Windows 7 and has AFAIK just been "refined"... you write you want to do this with your own custom handler...

IF you want to implement such a "virtual folder" and integrate it into Windows so that other applications can use it as a "virtual folder" then:

**To implement and install a "shell extension" (which basically are a bunch of COM interfaces):**

*Remark: If the system you are running on doesn't have .NET 4 then Microsoft recommended NOT to use .NET for this because of the inherent restriction with the older versions that one process can't run multiple framework versions at the same time. Depending on the OS etc. case it could be recommended to implement this with C/C++.

Even with .NET 4 as pointed out in the comments the code injection problem remains - i.e. if any .NET app prior .NET 4 and/or with a different .NET versions than your shell extension accesses the file open dialog for example it can/will fail.

**To circumvent that** you need to implement a native proxy DLL which gets loaded into the respective processes (like Windows Explorer) and communicates with your .NET implementation via IPC.*

In this specific case you need to build a shell extension which implements [IShellLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391719%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

That aside the implementation of shell extension is a really tough job... some links with information / samples / source code / libraries etc.:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774328%28v=VS.85%29.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codefx/archive/2010/09/14/writing-windows-shell-extension-with-net-framework-4-c-vb-net-part-1.aspx
- http://www.ssware.com/ezshell/ezshell.htm
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/ratingcolumn.aspx?q=shell+extensions+c%23
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguideindex.aspx
- http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/1428326d-7950-42b4-ad94-8e962124043e/

**To interact with a Windows 7 library** see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976027 and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Windows7APICodePack.aspx and http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DDW7LibrariesLite.aspx . Some require .NET 3.5 but since 3.5 is just 2.0 plus some additional assemblies it might be an option...

Comment: In fact, even with .net 4, .net shell extensions are not supported by MS. If I recall the issue is known as *code injection*.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not really... the main problem was IIRC not code injection but the fact that all shell extensions are loaded into the same process... before .NET 4 a process (in this case Windows Explorer) couldn't host different .NET versions at the same time... this point has changed with .NET 4 .

Comment: I think not. Before .net 4 the situation was as you described. But even after .net 4 the code injection issue remains and the official line from MS is not to use .net for shell extensions. Kind of a moot point because the question is about libraries and not about shell extensions. Not sure why your answer has so much about an orthogonal topic.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan added clarification... I have mentioned both because the OP said "custom handler" which got me thinking that he might want to implement a library/virtual folder and not just access one...

Comment: Fair point. I assumed the intent was just to access but you may be right. +1

Comment: Thank you Yahia, the links helped a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

The MSDN topics that seem most pertinent are:

- [Inside Windows 7:Introducing Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861346.aspx)
- [Windows Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758096%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Windows 7 Libraries: Developer Resources](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Libraries)

The library features are exposed through COM so there's no need for P/invoke.

However, since libraries only exist in Windows 7, and since Windows 7 has .net 3.5 as part of the OS, I would recommend that you put this part of your application in a .net 3.5 assembly. In fact the [API CodePack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack) assembly already does this for you.

Of course, since the CodePack is also delivered as source you could extract the necessary parts from there and do what is needed in order to build it against .net 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly searching in google, found this: [How to programmatically manipulate Windows 7 shell libraries](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976027)

if C# examples are not useful, it should be possible to export api methods used in c++ example.